# Dynamic dictionary in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to build a dictionary dynamically using pyspark, by reading the table structure on the oracle database. Here's a simplified version of my code

**predefined dictionary (convert_dict.py)**

```
conversions = {
    "COL1": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL2": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c, dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL3": lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c, dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL4": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("float")
}
```

**Main program**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from convert_dict import conversions


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("file_testing").getOrCreate()

table_name = "TEST_TABLE"
input_file_path = "file:\\\c:\Desktop\foo.txt"

sql_query = "(select listagg(column_name,',') within group(order by column_id) col from user_tab_columns where " \
      "table_name = '" + table_name + "' and column_name not in ('COL10', 'COL11','COL12') order by column_id) table_columns"
      
struct_schema = StructType([\
                StructField("COL1", StringType(), True),\
                StructField("COL2", StringType(), True),\
                StructField("COL3", StringType(), True),\
                StructField("COL4", StringType(), True),\
                ])
    

data_df = spark.read.schema(struct_schema).option("sep", ",").option("header", "true").csv(input_file_path)

validdateData = lines.withColumn(
                "dataTypeValidations",
                f.concat_ws(",",
                            *[
                               f.when(
                                    v(k).isNull() & f.col(k).isNotNull(),
                                    f.lit(k +  " not valid") 
                                ).otherwise(f.lit("None"))
                                
                                for k,v in conversions.items()
                            ]
                     )
                 )
                 
data_temp = validdateData
for k,v in conversions.items():
    data_temp = data_temp.withColumn(k,v(k))

validateData.show()

spark.stop()
```

If I am to change the above code to dynamically generate the dictionary from database

```
DATEFORMAT = "yyyyMMdd"
dict_sql = """
(select column_name,case when data_type = 'VARCHAR2' then 'string' when data_type in ( 'DATE','TIMESTAMP(6)') then 'date' when data_type = 'NUMBER' and NVL(DATA_SCALE,0) <> 0 then 'float' when data_type = 'NUMBER' and NVL(DATA_SCALE,0) = 0 then 'int'
end d_type from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST_TABLE' and column_name not in ('COL10', 'COL11','COL12')) dict
"""
column_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable", dict_sql)\
    .option("user",user).option("password",password).option("driver",driver).load()


conversions = {}
for row in column_df.rdd.collect():
    column_name = row.COLUMN_NAME
    column_type = row.D_TYPE
    if column_type == "date":
        conversions.update({column_name: lambda c:f.col(c)})
    elif column_type == "float":
        conversions.update({column_name: lambda c: f.col(c).cast("float")})
    elif column_type == "date":
        conversions.update({column_name: lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c, DATEFORMAT)).cast("date")})
    elif column_type == "int":
        conversions.update({column_name: lambda c: f.col(c).cast("int")})
    else:
        conversions.update({column_name: lambda c: f.col(c)})
```

The conversion of data-types doesn't work when the above dynamically generated dictionary is used. For example: if "COL2" contains "20210731", the resulting data from the above code stays the same, i.e. doesn't get converted to the correct date format. Where as the predefined dictionary works in correct manner.

Am I missing something here or is there a better way to implement dynamically generated dictionaries in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Had a rookie mistake in my code, in the if-then-else block, I had two separate statements for column_type == "date"

Comment: use comment section for this instead of selecting ans section